# Python nose: setting description attribute on generated tests

Tags: python, nose, attributeerror

I'm using test generators with nose. I'd like to have a custom description for each generated test.

[Nose documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-generators)  says:

> By default, the test name output for a generated test in verbose mode
>   will be the name of the generator function or method, followed by the
>   args passed to the yielded callable. If you want to show a different
>   test name, set the description attribute of the yielded callable.

However, this doesn't work:

```
class TestGraphics:
   def test_all(self):                                                                                             
        for i, tc in enumerate(testcases):                                                                       
            self.run_sim.description = str(i)
            yield(self.run_sim, tc[0], tc[1])
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'description'
```

How do I set the description attribute on the callable here?

Comment: try self.run_sim.__name__ = str(i)

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270342/python-nosetests-setting-the-test-description/24291694#24291694

Comment: @Oleksiy Not even close: the question doesn't use a test class, and the answer does not even use the yield test generation.

Answer (score 4):

The workarounds below, described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181201102949/http://achinghead.com:80/nosetests-generators-descriptions.html) and [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/python-nose/issues/244), appear to work.

```
from nose.tools import assert_true

class TestEven:

    def test_evens(self):
        for i in range(0, 5):
            yield self.check_even("check_even with {}".format(i)), i

    def check_even(self, desc):
        func = lambda n: assert_true(n % 2 == 0)
        func.description = desc
        return func
```

---

```
class TestEven:

    def test_evens(self):
        for i in range(0, 5):
            yield CheckEven(), i

class CheckEven:

    def __call__(self, n):
        self.description = "check_even with {}".format(n)
        assert n % 2 == 0
```

---

```
from functools import partial

class TestEven:

    def test_evens(self):
        for i in range(0, 5):
            f = partial(self.check_even, i)
            f.description = 'check_even with {}'.format(i)
            yield (f, )

    def check_even(self, n):
        assert n % 2 == 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, very helpful! I tried the third example since that is the one that fits my class paradigm best, but the problem there is, the 'self' passed to check_even doesn't seem to be the same as if I called it directly. For example, if I define a def setUp(self): self.x = 2, then I'm unable to refer to self.x from check_even(), although I have no trouble doing so if check_even() was called directly from the yield, without going through partial. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Use nose's [class level fixture](http://pythontesting.net/framework/nose/nose-fixture-reference/#class), as in `def setup_class(cls):` instead of `setUp():`.